# How to store response body in supertest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, supertest

I am testing very basic REST api with supertest. I want to save the item id received in response body and assign it to a variable. Using this id i want to make further tests like get-item-by-id or update-item-by-id. No official documentation has covered this so a beginner friendly answer would be very helpful.

test i have written

```js
const request = require("supertest")
let id;

describe('Products API', () => {
    it('GET  /products --> array of products', async () => {
        return request('http://localhost:3001')
            .get('/api/products')
            .expect(200)
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .then(response => {
                expect(response.body).toEqual(
                    expect.objectContaining({
                        success: true,
                        data: expect.any(Array)
                    })
                )
            })
    })

})
```

Comment: This is basic Javascript, unrelated to supertest... `const body = response.body;` ? `expect(body).toEqual(...)`?

Comment: where to put this ? i m beginner in testing

Comment: It's unrelated to testing, too. How do you use variables in your other server code, for example? `var/const/let`... You put it above your current usage of `response.body`. But still, it is already "a variable" called `response.body`, so why do you need to store it again as a different reference?

Comment: plz a small example..i didn't understand

Comment: _I want to save the item id received in response body_ - What item ID?  We cannot see what response your server returns. From what I can tell, you are getting more than one item, with multiple IDs

Comment: yes i want to save the item id of the first item in array... so i can perform further tests on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular JS variables

```
const request = require("supertest")

describe('Products API', () => {
    it('GET  /products --> array of products', async () => {
        return request('http://localhost:3001')
            .get('/api/products')
            .expect(200)
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .then(response => {
                expect(response.body).toEqual(
                    expect.objectContaining({
                        success: true,
                        data: expect.any(Array)
                    })
                )
                const data = response.body.data;

                expect(data.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)

                data.forEach(product => {
                    let id = product.id;
                    // expect data about the products
                }) 
            })
    })

})
```

> want to make further tests like get-item-by-id or update-item-by-id

You should explicitly test *those endpoints*, not via GET `/api/products`

E.g.

```
it('POST /products/{id} --> Updates a product', async () => {
  const id = 1;
  const result = request('http://localhost:3001')
    .post(`/api/products/${id}`)
    ...

  // TODO: Check the product was actually updated in the database, for example
});
```

More importantly, don't (or try not to) store variable state between tests.

Comment: thx.. i didn't know we could assgin variables directly inside expect.toEqual

Comment: I didnt. Its inside the `then()` function body handler

Comment: oh ... how i missed that ! was stuck for 2 days

Comment: i cant use custom id, as i have set mongodb json schema to accept only ObjectId type ids

Comment: i explicitly tried to use app.js instead of //localhost:3001/api/products but that didn't work as my database connection reside in server.js

Comment: HTTP methods don't know anything about Mongo. You either have path parameters or body parameters. Both of which can be passed into supertest

Comment: Your test function should start an in-memory mongo database. https://jestjs.io/docs/mongodb